# In oh-my-zsh, how do I get the bindkey keymap string for the key combination I'm pressing?

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to make the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> keys go back and forward in command line history, respectively. While googling how to do this, I saw a lot of commenters giving their opinions on certain keymap formats. I wasn't able to learn which format is the most compatible, but I got an overall sense that every keyboard can be different.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there's a command or program I can run where, if I press a key combination, it'll print the keymap string for it. That way I can be sure I'm using the appropriate key man from my keyboard. Alternatively, if there is a list of universally compatible keymaps, I could use that as an answer, too.

Note I am using WSL2 (Windows subsystem for Linux). Ubuntu is my distro.

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question because I found a duplicate. I don't want to delete this because I spent a lot of time searching before I found this duplicate. Maybe this'll improve the dupe's search engine ranking.